# does single step interrupt(01H interrupt) clear TF flag after every instruction?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, interrupt, eflags

i want to use single step interrupt and i understand that for make this interrupt work for every instruction the TF flag should be 1 (TF=1).
and in my code i see single step interrupt work but after some instructions(maybe after every output) it stop and i should make TF=1 again to continue code and continue display outputs).
does that mean after every instruction or after special instructions cause TF=0 again ?
this code i used to set TF=1

```
 asm{
            PUSHF 
            MOV BP,SP  
            OR WORD PTR[BP+0],0100H 
            POPF  
        }
```

Comment: Please specify to which CPU architecture your question applies, by setting an appropriate tag (e.g. [`x86-64`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86-64/info)).

Comment: i used xinu that worked by dosbox

Comment: (Assuming x86) The CPU certainly clears the trap flag before calling the debug exception handler; otherwise the handler would attempt to single-step itself.  What's not clear is whether TF is set or cleared in the FLAGS that are pushed when the handler is called.  The Intel Software Developer's Manual doesn't seem to explain this (looking at Vol 3B 17.3.1.4).

Comment: xinu is the operating system, not the architecture (which would be like x86, ARM, MIPS, etc).  Dosbox emulates x86 so I suppose that is the architecture.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm sure the trap flag is set in the pushed flag word.

Comment: Interrupts, including the Trace Interrupt, clear TF on entry. The idea is that the `iret` restores TF=1 to trap again. (However, after an interrupt call, `iret` runs one more instruction and then causes a Trace Interrupt. That looks like the tracing happening "too late" as you will miss an instruction.) @NateEldredge: Unless the instruction is `iret` or `popf` the Trace Interrupt certainly pushes `fl` with TF=1. For those two I'm unsure.

Comment: i used this code to set TF=1 asm{
  PUSHF 
        MOV BP,SP  
        OR WORD PTR[BP+0],0100H 
        POPF  
 }

Comment: i will edit topic and add the code i used to set TF=1

Comment: I checked on dosemu2 in V86M (using its CPU simulator, so may be inaccurate) and in a 16-bit code segment in DPMI (using `-I "cpu_vm_dpmi native"` so likely running on the host, `cpuid` gives AuthenticAMD in this mode). Both modes show that `popf` and `iret`, while causing a Trace Interrupt, will reset the TF to 0 in the pushed `fl` if what they pop has TF=0. Full output here: https://pushbx.org/ecm/test/20220504/tfclear.txt

Comment: Off-topic: I think I've read that some x86-16 compilers don't save call-preserved registers that you modify in `asm{}` blocks, so you need to avoid that or push/pop BP.  It's cheapest to just avoid it: `pushf / pop ax` / `or ax, 0x0100` (same size as `or ah, 1` which needs a modrm+imm8) / `push ax` / `popf`.  (Or maybe I'm mis-remembering and you had to save/restore *any* register you used in inline asm, in which case that doesn't help.)  TF is outside the low 8 bits of FLAGS so you *can't* LAHF / SAHF. like you could for some other FLAGS bits.

Comment: Test is explained some more [in this changeset](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/45067f20604b).

Comment: I just repeated my test on a real (686) DOS PC, using JemmEx + HDPMI32 (first V86M and then PM) or HimemX + HDPMI32 (first R86M and then PM). Result is the same: `popf` and `iret` will push TF=0 onto the Trace Interrupt's `fl` stack slot when they popped an `fl` with TF=0. Otherwise, TF=1 is pushed onto the Trace Interrupt's stack frame.